# Android, Integer.parseInt() doesn't work

Tags: android

Sorry for my bad english.. So.. i have this code:

```
    void inputthread() {
final Handler handler = new Handler(); 
final int misurazione[]={0};
final byte delimiter = 65; //This is the ASCII code for a newline character
stopWorker = false;
readBufferPosition = 0;
readBuffer = new byte[1024];
workerThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
 while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() && !stopWorker) 
 {
  try 
  {
    int bytesAvailable = mmInputStream.available();            
    if(bytesAvailable > 0) 
    { 
        byte[] packetBytes = new byte[bytesAvailable];
        mmInputStream.read(packetBytes);
        for(int i=0;i<bytesAvailable;i++) 
        {
            byte b = packetBytes[i];
            if(b == delimiter)
            {
              byte[] encodedBytes = new byte[readBufferPosition];
              System.arraycopy(readBuffer, 0, encodedBytes, 0, encodedBytes.length);
              String data = new String(encodedBytes, "US-ASCII");   
              readBufferPosition = 0;
                try {
                      misurazione[0] = Integer.parseInt(data);
                      handler.post(new Runnable() 
                          {
                              public void run()
                              {
                                txtaggiorna.setText(misurazione[0]);
                              }
                          }); 
                    } catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {}
              }
                else {
                  readBuffer[readBufferPosition++] = b;
                }
       }
     }
  }catch (IOException ex) 
      {
        stopWorker = true;
      }
}
  }
});

workerThread.start();
  }
```

Android receives bytes from arduino containing only numeric string and i want to convert it into integer, but Integer.parseInt(data) doesn't work and i don't know why..

Comment: "doesn't work" is not descriptive enough. What is actually happening (versus what did you expect to happen)? Are you seeing a crash? If so, post a stack trace.

Comment: Are you sure that data contains only numbers?

Comment: Please post Logcat here (along with the data being logged), so that everyone here can share their inputs. The only errors with Integer.ParseInt() that could happen will be if the passed in data is null or is contains non-numeric characters.

Comment: It shows me this error "No package identifier when getting value of resource number"

Answer (score 0):

```
 String data = new String(encodedBytes.toString(), "US-ASCII");
```

Comment: Can you please add some explanation? What is wrong with what the OP is doing, and how does this code resolve it?